# Create link to a commit or build in another organization

Tags: azure-devops

Anyone who knows about a workaround to create links/relations between work items in one organization and commit/builds in another organization using REST API? The URL in the payload below resolves to a project/commit within the current organization only.

```
    {
        "rel": "ArtifactLink",
        "url": "vstfs:///Git/Commit/83c6cf52-c501-4095-b5a0-b1c61d1308b4%2Ffa2069dc-d5da-41cf-ac69-b90be7dface4%2F6afcfe889c6f7858d85c93b1ed9fd0d0c8711f23",
        "attributes": {
            "authorizedDate": "2023-10-18T13:59:56.18Z",
            "id": 23918127,
            "resourceCreatedDate": "2023-10-18T13:59:56.18Z",
            "resourceModifiedDate": "2023-10-18T13:59:56.18Z",
            "revisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "name": "Fixed in Commit"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my investigation, only [Remote work link types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops#remote-work-link-types) can support linking **work items** defined in different organizations, and the organizations must be under the same Azure AD.

Considering you want to link commit/builds, you can try using [Hyperlink link type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops#hyperlink-link-type) as a workaround. You can use this [Add a hyperlink REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP#add-a-hyperlink) to link any URL (including your commit/builds URL) to Work item. The disadvantage is that this is only one-way link. It just links to commit/builds from work item but cannot link back to work item from commit/builds.